# Does it work to deploy a React project to Netlify while the Laravel backend is deployed in Heroku?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, heroku, netlify

I have a mini project for practicing my skills in React and Laravel and I wanted to deploy it online so I can add it to my portfolio and also for future job applications.

Does it work if I deploy the front end code (React) in Netlify and the back end code (Laravel) in Heroku?

Wanted to test it out since its both free to deploy in those ways. I already tried deploying both front end and back end in just Heroku and wanted to test some things differently.

Comment: Yep this is fine, as long as your backend is set up to accept connections from your frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible you just have to add Functions to your front app.

Tutorial React APP to Netlify :
https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/07/22/deploy-react-apps-in-less-than-30-seconds/

Function API example :
https://functions-playground.netlify.com/

Hope this helps.